# Update nuget pacakge adds Error Condition to csproj

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on a project with multiple solutions. I recently added a reference to a Nuget package, X in one of my solutions. This caused some version conflicts so i updated the versions of x in all my solutions. Now in solutions which had a conflict, i can see the below lines have been added

```
<Import Project="..\packages\X.3.3.2.0\build\X.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\X.3.3.2.0\build\X.props')" />

<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\X.3.3.2.0\build\X.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\X.3.3.2.0\build\X.props'))" />
```

Does anyone know why this gets added and what is the significance of these lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NuGet packages may add build logic to consuming projects by having `.props` and/or `.targets` files inside their `build` folder.

When installed into "classic" csproj files (packages.config method), NuGet adds these statements to the csproj file to include this logic. What this actually is depends on the package. Some set values for use during the build process, some add content files that are copied to the build output and some add custom build steps (transformations etc.).

The `<Import … />` element consumes the logic file, with a condition to prevent against the file missing - e.g. when the NuGet packages have not yet been restored (fresh clone/checkout, build server). If the `Condition` wasn't checking if the file exists, the project file may fail to load in VS.

The `<Error … />` element then emits an error message if this file does not exist so that VS will show an error after the project has been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused because VS doesn't manage nuget packages very well. If you move or rearrange project locations, you might have to manually correct the paths in the project file. Also, make sure that the paths for project A packages don't actually point at the project B package directory. I have seen a lot of problems with nuget packages caused by invalid paths in project files.

Also, answering your question directly, I believe that the reason you see a single error condition check, is because it was added by a nuget package. Adding most nuget packages won't trigger this check being added to your project file, only nuget packages that depend on other nuget packages. (For example, something that depended on a common package like Newtonsoft.Json might add this line of code to insure that a proper version was present)

I think (but I am not sure) that this is controlled by the package author setting a flag or something, as opposed to VS automatically tracing dependency chains.

Removing those checks is harmless and will allow you to complete an otherwise solid build in a pinch, but if you do that you risk a runtime error if the proper assembly isn't present.